# How would I open my Chrome app in split screen rather than a new window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm doing a little research on how to develop a Chrome app for a project I have in mind. I would like to open my app in a split screen inside a person's browser tab, so that they can still see the webpage in the browser while interacting with my app. (In the same way that the console and developer tools work.)

Everything I've seen so far indicates that apps can only open a new window, not "split the screen".  Is that correct? I haven't seen it explicitly stated.

If splitting the screen is possible - what's the notation/api?

The other option I'm aware of would be to create a DevTools extension (that operates in the Developer Tools split screen window.) I'm not sure that's preferable for this particular app, though

thanks.

Comment: Why can't you leave positioning up to your users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Chrome Apps cannot integrate with the browser UI, that's a design choice by Google.

If you need to interact with a browser tab, it must be an extension.

A DevTools panel is not a bad idea, since it frees you from the burden of injecting your own UI into the page. Otherwise, you'll need to modify the page's DOM (perhaps by injecting an iframe with your extension's page).

There is a proposal for a sidebar API, but [it's not implemented](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51084) (or rejected) as of yet.